# Not able to install Nokogiri 1.6.0 on Mac (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: ruby, macos, nokogiri

I am not able to install Nokogiri on my Mac running Mountain Lion.

I tried to install it using command:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'
```

I get this output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:48: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.1/lib/mini_portile.rb:215: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes

creating Makefile

make
compiling html_document.c
gcc-4.7: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wshorten-64-to-32'
make: *** [html_document.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/Cellar/ruby193/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: We need more information. Do you have the current XCode installed, along with it's associated command-line tools?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error with 1.6.1.  I solved this on OS X Mavericks by switching to `llvm-gcc`.

```
CC=llvm-gcc gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

Comment: Helped with installing quite a few of gems even on El Capitan. Thanks!